# Referencing Select Drop-down Value in Yii

Tags: php, yii

Question: using a `CActiveForm` `dropDownList` I'm trying to have it post the selected value on change. But I'm not sure how can I reference the currently selected dropdown value?

Code thus far is:

```
$form->dropDownList($model,'condition',$model->getConditionOptions(), array('submit'=>array('theme/build','id'=>$model->id,'condition'=>'')));
```

Where `getConditionOptions` returns an array of dropdown values, 'condition' should be the selected value from this dropdown.

Comment: you should use depended dropdown, there is a wiki article about this: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/24/creating-a-dependent-dropdown/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't specify an attribute just to have the current value - that defeats the purpose of a dropdown.

To get the current value of a dropdown, in your jquery, use jQuery's val: http://api.jquery.com/val/, e.g.:

```
$("#DropDownID").val()
```

**Edit:** Your real question seems to be how to have content update after changing a dropdown, dependent on the value of the drop down.  This would be accomplished via AJAX.  Yii provides a special [AJAX](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#ajax-detail) array for this e.g.:

```
$form->dropDownList($model,
                    'condition',
                    $model->getConditionOptions(),
                    array('submit'=>array('theme/build',
                          'id'=>$model->id,
                          'ajax'=>array('url'=>CController::createURL('controller/action'),
                                        'data'=>'$("#' . $model->id . '")',                                   
                                        'update'=>'#otherID', //selector to update
                                        )
                                    )
                          )
                    );
```

Then, on your controller side, you could get the value using [getParam](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#getParam-detail).  Note that whatever you want to update should be echo'd back, as opposed to using render.

**Edit 2:** If you don't want to use jQuery, and just reload the whole page, you should just submit the form, e.g.:

```
$form->dropDownList($model, 'condition', $model->getConditionOptions(), array('submit'=>CController::createURL('controller/action')))
```

Then in your controller, you'd still use getParam and then render a new page.

Comment: Where would I put this jQuery? I'm attempting to set a controller variable $condition with the value of a dropdown every time it's value has changed.

Comment: @MichaelGruber Updated answer to address your comment.  Remember, javascript is going to run client side, and PHP is going to run server side, so in general, you will not have persistent variables in your controller and in the javascript.

Comment: The thing is I'm not sure Ajax is what I want. I don't want to update a specific div or anything I want to essentially reload the page with a new variable parameter passed in (the value of the dropdown)

Comment: If you don't want to use AJAX, then you just want to submit the form and go from there.

Comment: I agree. What I'm not sure about it is submitting the value on change and accessing the value within the controller.

Comment: @MichaelGruber Updated with code on how to submit the form onchange

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you could do this is like this:

```
//define your dropdownlist
$form->dropDownList(
    $model,
    'condition',
    $model->getConditionOptions(),
    //your ajax call
    'ajax'  => array( 
        'type'  => 'POST',
        'url'   => 'theme/build'.
        'data'  => array(
            'id' => $model->id,
            'condition' =>'js:jQuery(this).val()', //current value
        )
);
```

EDIT:
To get current selected option:

```
$('#dropbox').val();
```

or

```
$('#dropbox :selected').val();
```

To get current selected option text

```
$('#dropbox :selected').text();
```